# json check empty data

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I would check if my JSON response (data) is empty

```
$.ajax ({
type    : 'POST',
url     : get.php,
dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       console.log(data.lenght);
    }
});
```

**GET.PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$stmt = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$_assoc = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $_assoc = $row;
}
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($_assoc);
```

**JSON RESPONSE**

```
{"foo":"6","bar":"3436","id":4,"code":""}
```

**EMPTY JSON RESPONSE**

```
[]
```

I tried with data.length but returned undefined.

Comment: Typo, the property name is `length`: `if (data.length)`. First thing to do when debugging JS is to check the console - syntax errors such as this are always displayed there.

Comment: note that this line inside the loop `$_assoc = $row;` values will be overwritten in every iteration

Comment: @mcCrossan I'm sorry but I do not understand, I have no errors in the console

Comment: @Ghost - I know this. Thanks

Comment: Why downvote? No one tells me how can I do? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question within the question, you can post it as an answer. When someone has the same issue and wants to go to the answers, it looks like there are none...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

I solved this way.

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

Thanks for yours downvote!